# How safe is to store files into the document directory?

Tags: ios, swift, download, nsdocumentdirectory

I am writing an iOS app in Swift and Xcode where I allow users to download some files from a server and to store them into the iPhone's document directory.

How safe is it to do so?

Is it possible for a user to access one of these files from outside the app, for example by connecting their phone to a computer, and move them around or share them? If a user has a jailbroken iPhone, could he get a way to access the downloaded files in other ways other than the one I allow within my app?

And if so, should I encrypt my files when I download them?

Comment: @DávidPásztor at the moment I am simply NOT encrypting my files at all. SO is not a free code writing website as you say in your comment and I am NOT asking for code. Read my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jailbroken iPhone i think yes it's possible to access apps directories.

For normal iPhone I'm pretty sure other apps can't access it as all third-party apps are “sandboxed"

[https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec15bfe098e/web#:~:text=Sandboxing,information%20stored%20by%20other%20apps](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec15bfe098e/web#:%7E:text=Sandboxing,information%20stored%20by%20other%20apps).

And no idea about connecting their phone to a computer.